# Don't understand CI urls, adding prefix to my urls

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following link:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/gallery/dogs">Dogs</a></li>
```

In my config.php I have:

```
$config['base_url'] = '127.0.0.1/Won/';
```

And when I go to link on that link above, it points to this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Won/127.0.0.1/Won//gallery/dogs
```

Yes I have tried to search for a solution to this prior to asking.

Comment: I think, trailing slash may not be there at $config['base_url'] = '127.0.0.1/Won/';

Answer (score 0):

Your base url is set as:
 `127.0.0.1/Won/`

Your html anchor uses this code for the href:
`<?php echo base_url() ?>/gallery/dogs`

If you inspect the DOM using your browsers developer tools you should see that your href is being set as:
`127.0.0.1/Won//gallery/dogs`

To solve this you need to change your configs `base url` to the following:
`http://127.0.0.1/Won/`

You also need to remove the extra forward slash from your anchors href code. The correct code would be:

`<li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>gallery/dogs">Dogs</a></li>`

Comment: The correct code would be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/Won/';`. I can't see your answer solving anything, because the browser is interpreting 127.0.0.1 as if it were a folder inside the current path.

Comment: You are correct, you need the `http://` at the begining or it will be interpreted as a folder.